# How to compare order of elements in two vectors in R?

Tags: r

I have two vectors with the same elements but in different order, how can I find the new position of the elements ? `which()` should do the trick but I'm unable to figure out how to do that, any idea ?

For example :

```
v1 <- c("paris", "new york", "london", "sidney")
v2 <- c("sidney", "new york", "paris", "london")

> which(v1 %in% v2)
[1] 1 2 3 4
> which(v1 == v2)
integer(0)
```

What I'm trying to do is something like  :

```
> find_new_position(v1, v2)
[1] 3 2 4 1
```

Comment: check out `?match`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [match](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.html)

```
match(v1, v2)
```

Returns the indices for matching elements, NA if element is not in the list to match against.